# mysql dpkg returned an error code

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, dpkg

Since Ubuntu 16.04 I can´t install new mysql-server version (5.7).

```
mysql dpkg returned an error code
...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.7
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I have tried to reinstall. I have all deleted and installed. But the error message still exists.

Any Ideas?

I have followed this from https://askubuntu.com/questions/760724/16-04-upgrade-broke-mysql-server

```
Back up your my.cnf file in /etc/mysql and remove it
Remove the folder /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/
Verify you don't have a my.cnf file stashed somewhere else (I did in my home dir!)
Backup and remove /etc/mysql/debian.cnf files (not sure if needed, but just in case)
sudo apt purge mysql-server mysql-server-5.7 mysql-server-core-5.7
sudo apt install mysql-server
```

Still i am getting the error.